# Chart for web request visualization

Tags: javascript, logging, charts, httprequest

I would like to visualize requests that my application is getting. I would like to create such chart:

- on x there is timestamp
- request is visualized by rectangle
- when requests are parallel, the rectangles are stacked

This is explainded on image below:

- second request is stacked, because first request is not finished
- third request is behind first one, because first one is already finished

Do you know some tools that are able to create such chart based on log data, or at least libraries that allows easily create such chart?

[image: chart of requests]

Comment: Are you referring to Gantt charts, basically?

Comment: @AdrianWragg in Gantt chart in y axis you have description on task, and here rectangles are stacked randomly

Comment: @AdrianWragg actually doing calculations, I think I can use Gantt chart easily...

Comment: If you count your requests as tasks, I'm sure you can find a nice component; what you have is a classic project management view (great way to show what you're after, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

How about data-driven documents?
[d3js.org](http://d3js.org/)
It can read data from xml/json and other formats